How to explicitly list allowed keyword arguments in python for IDE support?
I'm using
argparse.ArgumentParser
in python and giving users the option to add their own functions to my script. For that, I'm giving them a function that generates data that gets used in argparse's
add_argument()
function. I noticed that add_argument's signature is
add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs)
but when looking at the documentation in vscode I can see all the different arguments it can get (action, nargs, const, default, etc.).

How does python do it? As far as I know when you give the user **kwargs it is shown as **kwargs and that's it.
I looked all over this site and the internet in general but I can't find the syntax used for it.

Look at the linked argparse.py file to see how it handles the function arguments.  The exact mix it uses depends varies, depending in part on thee action value/subclass.  The documentation list is not autogenerated.

The expected way customize add_arguement is to subclass Action.

I'm not looking to customize add_argument, rather, I want to use the default add_argument and transfer it's args' and kwargs' documentation to my function's args' and kwargs' documentation, something like
def createMethod(getData: HANDLER_FUNC_TYPE, alias: str,  *args: str, **kwargs) -> ARG_STORAGE_TYPE:
ArgumentParser().add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
return {'alias': alias, 'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs, 'getData': getData}

Are you aware of stubs? That's probably what VSCode is pulling from here.

I'm not aware of stubs, please explain

typeshed stub for argparse.add_argument:  https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/argparse.pyi#L86-L101

VSCode's language server is pulling from the stub file in the typeshed, where the current definition is:
def add_argument(
    self,
    *name_or_flags: str,
    action: _ActionStr | type[Action] = ...,
    nargs: int | _NArgsStr | _SUPPRESS_T | None = None,
    const: Any = ...,
    default: Any = ...,
    type: _ActionType = ...,
    choices: Iterable[_T] | None = ...,
    required: bool = ...,
    help: str | None = ...,
    metavar: str | tuple[str, ...] | None = ...,
    dest: str | None = ...,
    version: str = ...,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> Action: ...

Sidenote: It looks like you're using Pylance, which is adding some detail to the types. For example with _T@add_argument it's saying that _T is scoped to add_argument. I'm using Jedi which shows different details.
Reference
Editing Python in Visual Studio Code § Autocomplete and IntelliSense

Pylance is the default language server for Python in VS Code, and is installed alongside the Python extension to provide IntelliSense features.
Pylance is based on Microsoft's Pyright static type checking tool, leveraging type stubs (.pyi files) and lazy type inferencing to provide a highly-performant development experience.

See also

Stub files - mypy documentation


P.S. I believe PyCharm does the same thing and these pages are relevant: Stubs, Code reference information (Parameter Info popup, inlay hints, ...)
